# Who laid the megalithic foundation stones under the wailing wall?

Tags: history, yerushalayim-jerusalem, ezra-nechemya, king-solomon

These stones under the Western Wall are of impeccable craftsmanship and required seemingly superhuman handling:

[image: Megalithic foundation stones under Western Wall]

My thoughts run to:

- Ezra-Nehemiah
- Solomon-Hiram
- Herod

Do we know?

Comment: Very interesting question; image link not working for me.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herodian_architecture#Herodian_masonry

Comment: The Wikipedia entry on the Western Wall  - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Wall - says the 17 courses below street level, and some above, are from Herod's time.  He expanded the Temple mount and built it as a retaining wall for his upgrade to it.  His stonework is recognizable because the stones(ashlars I think is the technical term) are , first, larger than the layers added later above them, and second, they usually have a "frame" or "edge" chiseled into their borders for aesthetic reasons.

Comment: Technically they aren't under the wall. They ARE the wall. They were built at ground level and in the last 2000 years the valley on one side of the wall has largely filled in with dirt, burying the bottom half of the wall.

Comment: @Gary  Might the idea that Herod built on existing megalithic stones with far inferior stone and stonework match the evidence more simply?

Comment: @Ruminator - No, IMO. Herod's other structures have the same type of edgework, as well as other common features.  He used up Judea's resources pretty extravagantly, when he wasn't paying off his Roman pals.  See- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herodian_architecture  Oops, DoubleAA already found it..

Comment: How is this about Judaism?

Comment: @ezra History of an important structure in Judaism. Seems on-topic to me.

Comment: I wonder if perhaps Herod recycled (and stylized) more ancient stones? Relevant passages are: 1 Kings 7:9-12 and Ezra 3:10-13.

Comment: @Doniel why is this structure important in Judaism?

Comment: @DoubleAA The base of the Kosel???

Comment: @Doniel I think that's what we're talking about

Comment: @DoubleAA Agreed, the Kosel seems to be pretty important.

Comment: @Doniel I don't agree. Not sure what importance you're seeing. Maybe you're thinking of something on the mountain up top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Western Wall in its entirety was built by King Herod. And yes the stones are quite impressive. This is one of the wonders of the ancient world (I think Josephus calls it that). The top half of the wall was destroyed with the Temple and rebuilt cheaply over the years.

For a full treatment of who built what of the Temple Mount walls, see Ritimyer's book The Quest.

Answer (score -1):

My guide on the Kosel Tunnel Tours (in 2011) explained that they are the work of the simple Jews (not Neviim or leaders) who had a great love and desire to beautify the House of Hashem... He said they were each chiseled by hand and transported through some sophisticated system. I am not sure how much of a source this YU graduate is, but to the best of my recollection these were the words he used.

Comment: I thank you for sharing the tour guide's explanation however tour guides are notorious for making stuff up! Without a corroborating primary source I don't think that information can be counted on. Peace.

Comment: @Ruminator any information is useful. it is acurate and true that this is how these stones are described by the tour guides